# tdCls is not working properly in Extjs Grid Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a grid panel with lots of records. I have color coded some of the columns in the grid through the following CSS. While previewing it is looking good.

[image]

But after deployment the color coding is effecting for alternate rows as shown below.
[image]

There was no error caught in the Firebug too. Please help me in solving this one.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    <View>
    <ext:GridView StripeRows="false" />
    </View>
```

in your grid

Comment: Thanks much. I forgot about the StripeRows :)

Comment: You're welcome :) If you don't mind accept as answer if its the solution to your problem :)